# Can object detection models trained online using automl be exportet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to export a model i trained using the Gcloud AutoML Object Detection feature. The model trained online no problem, but I now would like to deploy this onto a different device.

I found the following documentation to export the model: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/deploy#export-example-cli

However, when doing this with my object detection model I get the error:
Unsupported model export format [tf_saved_model] for model [MODELID]

Could it be that object detection models can't be exportet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are [Edge models](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train-edge) on Cloud AutoML Vision (classification) which can be exported, the Cloud-hosted (online) custom models can't be exported neither on [Vision (classification)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train) nor [Vision Object Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/train). Additionally, AutoML Vision for object detection only provides cloud-hosted models at the present time, so you can't create exportable Edge models.

There's an ongoing feature request to allow to [export models from AutoML Vision](https://issuetracker.google.com/113122585). This tracker covers both AutoML Vision Classification and Object Detection.